# sleepForTimeInterval Timeout freezes app

Tags: objective-c, timer, ios4

I'm trying to wait X amount of seconds in between actions.
When using `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3.0];` the app freezes for the set amount of time. How can I timeout without disrupting the `main thread`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't block the main runloop (which handles user input) and expect your app to remain responsive. Consider using an [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003747).